# Python asyncio: function or coroutine, which to use?

Tags: python, asynchronous, coroutine, python-asyncio, python-3.5

I'm wondering if there are any noticeable differences in performance between `foo` and `bar`:

```py
class Interface:
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.loop = loop

    def foo(self, a, b):
        return self.loop.run_until_complete(self.bar(a, b))

    async def bar(self, a, b):
        v1 = await do_async_thing1(a)
        for i in range(whatever):
            do_some_syncronous_work(i)
        v2 = await do_async_thing2(b, v1)
        return v2

async def call_foo_bar(loop):
    a = 'squid'
    b = 'ink'
    interface = Interface(loop)
    v_foo = interface.foo(a, b)
    v_bar = await interface.bar(a, b)
```

But will the use of `run_until_complete` cause any practical, noticeable different to running my program?

(The reason I ask is I'm building an interface class which will accommodate decomposable "back-ends" some of which could be asynchronous. I'm hoping to use standard functions for the public (reusable) methods of the interface class so one API can be maintained for all code without messing up the use of asynchronous back-ends where an event-loop is available.)

**Update:** I didn't check the code properly and the first version was completely invalid, hence rewrite.

Comment: It actually depends. `Foo` will be executed synchronously while `Bar` not. It might happen that the scheduling/distribution might be important, i.e. it might make a difference for final user.

Comment: Yes, `foo()` is a blocking call.
Also `run_until_complete` cannot be called with already running event loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loop.run_until_complete()` should be used **outside** of coroutine on very top level. Calling `run_until_complete()` with *active* (running) event loop is forbidden.

Also `loop.run_until_complete(f)` is a blocking call: execution thread is blocked until `f` *coroutine* or *future* becomes done.

`async def` is a proper way to write asynchronous code by making concurrent *coroutines* which may communicate with each other.

`async def` requires running event loop (either `loop.run_until_complete()` or `loop.run_forever()` should be called).

Comment: Ok, so there's no reasonably way to build an interface which can be used for both synchronous and asynchronous code.

Comment: No.
For now the best recommended way is to build *async* interface and make *sync* clone of them by adding stub functions running async counterparts with help of `run_until_complete()`

Answer (score 1):

There is a world of difference. It is a `SyntaxError` to use `await` in a normal function `def` function.

```
import asyncio

async def atest():
    print("hello")

def test():
    await atest()

async def main():
    await atest()
    test()
```

--

```
File "test.py", line 9
    await atest()
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Yes but as explained lets assume we're calling them thing (coroutine or function) from inside a coroutine.

Comment: No, it's a `SyntaxError` no mater what. You can easily try it for yourself.

Comment: yes you're right, my bad for not checking the code before submitted the question. I'll update the question.

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe so. I have used both and have not really seen a difference. I prefer foo just because I have used it more and understand it a bit better, but it is up to you.